# how to render proper page based on user visit before on initial page load in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Basically my idea is to load home page , if user visits for first time and if user has already visited display the details of user.

There is no login for this app.Its like anonymous login.
Where to write the function like before Route ? on initial load itself it should go to correct page

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this with Route Guard `beforeEnter` method. For more information see https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/foo',
      component: Foo,
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        // Do your logic here.
      }
    }
  ]
})
```